# How to round all values in one-dimensional numpy.ndarray

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have one-dimensional `numpy.ndarray` called `y` that contains natural logarithm values. I want to convert all these values into a linear scale and round, using just a single line of code.
The following code works, but it provides incorrect results. For example, the first value in `result` is 0, instead of 15.

```
result = [round(np.expm1(x)) for x in range(len(y))]
```

Comment: Since you are using NumPy, you can simply operate on the entire array `y` at once with `np.round(np.expm1(y))`. Using list comprehension with NumPy is slow and often unnecessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
result = [round(np.expm1(x)) for x in y]
```

or

```
result = [round(np.expm1(y[x])) for x in range(len(y))]
```

The way you have it now, you are putting the array index into the function.